# Issue with EmailJS + React Hooks + 'preventDefault'

Tags: reactjs, forms, event-handling, react-hooks, form-submit

I have been working with React for a couple of months and I have decided to try to build my portfolio. Working on it, I am using by default a Material UI form to be contacted using the EmailJS platform. I am sure it is very simple, but I have been going for hours with this matter going around without finding the solution.
  I do not know if the problem lies in the 'Custom Input' of Material UI Librarie or is it something else related to the event onClick.
My problem is with the “e.preventDefault” of undefined.
 It is probably something simple, but for trying to solve it I think I ended up getting dizzy and confused me more than the beginning.
  Thank you!

This is the code with a validator for the form :

```
    const [values, setValues] = useState({
        name: '',
        email: '',
        message: '',
  });
  const handleChange = (name)=> (e) => {
        setValues({ ...values, [e.target.id]: e.target.value });
  };

  const isFormValid = () => {
        if (!values.name || !values.email || !values.message) {

      return false;}
      else {
      return true;}

  };

  const sendEmail =(e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    emailjs.sendForm('gmail', 'template_AILAIHUt', e.target, 'user_kPqhCaNpQHv75H92RjVhj')
      .then((result) => {
          console.log(result.text + 'funciona');
      }, (error) => {
          console.log(error.text + 'no funciona');
      });
  }

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        if (!isFormValid()) {
      //message of error in the screen, maybe sweet alerts
      console.log('falta algo')
    }
    else{ sendEmail(e)}
    };



  return (
    <div className={classes.section}>
      <div className={classes.container}>
        <GridContainer justify="center">
          <GridItem xs={12} sm={12} md={4}>
            <Card>
              <form className={classes.form}>
                <CardHeader style={{ fontWeight: "fontWeightBold" }} color='primary' className={classes.cardHeader}>
                  <h4>Let's create something together </h4>

                </CardHeader>
                <CardBody>
                  <CustomInput
                    labelText="Name..."
                    id="name"
                    required={true}
                    formControlProps={{
                      required: true,
                      fullWidth: true
                    }}
                    inputProps={{ 
                      required: true,
                      onChange: handleChange(),
                      id:'name',
                      value: values.name,
                      type: "text",
                      endAdornment: (
                        <InputAdornment position="end">
                          <People className={classes.inputIconsColor} />
                        </InputAdornment>
                      )
                    }}
                  />
                  <CustomInput
                    labelText="Email..."
                    id="email"
                    type='email'
                    required={true}
                    onChange={handleChange()}
                    formControlProps={{
                      required: true,
                      fullWidth: true
                    }}
                    inputProps={{
                      required: true,
                      onChange: handleChange(),
                      id:'email',
                      value: values.email,
                      type: "email",
                      endAdornment: (
                        <InputAdornment position="end">
                          <Email className={classes.inputIconsColor} />
                        </InputAdornment>
                      )
                    }}
                  />
                  <CustomInput
                    labelText="Be free..."
                    id="message"
                    required={true}
                    formControlProps={{
                      size: 'large', 
                      rows: '4',
                      required: true,
                      fullWidth: true
                    }}
                    inputProps={{
                      multiline: true,
                      required: true,
                      onChange: handleChange(),
                      id:'message',
                      value: values.message,
                      multiline: true,
                      type: "text",
                      endAdornment: (
                        <InputAdornment position="end">
                          <Icon className={classes.inputIconsColor}>
                            <SendIcon  className={classes.inputIconsColor}/>
                          </Icon> 
                        </InputAdornment>
                      ),
                      autoComplete: "off"
                    }}
                  />
                </CardBody>
                <CardFooter className={classes.cardFooter}>
                  <Button simple color="primary" size="lg" onClick={(e) => handleSubmit()}>
                    Submit
                  </Button> 
                </CardFooter>
              </form>
            </Card>
          </GridItem>
        </GridContainer>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: could you describe the error you are getting? What is console logged?

Comment: I already edit the first comment, sorry. The issue is with the “preventDefault” of undefined

Comment: then please have a look at my solution, I solved this issue :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make sure to add the errors you are receiving or at what point your code stops working so we can have better idea of what is wrong.

I am seeing a few things in your code already, I will fix them below and write a big comment above each fix so you can identify where I have changed the code.

```
    const [values, setValues] = useState({
        name: '',
        email: '',
        message: '',
  });
  const handleChange = (name)=> (e) => {
        setValues({ ...values, [e.target.id]: e.target.value });
  };

  const isFormValid = () => {
        if (!values.name || !values.email || !values.message) {

      return false;}
      else {
      return true;}

  };

  const sendEmail = (e) => {
    emailjs.sendForm('gmail', 'template_AILAIHUt', e.target, 'user_kPqhCaNpQHv75H92RjVhj')
      .then((result) => {
          console.log(result.text + 'funciona');
      }, (error) => {
          console.log(error.text + 'no funciona');
      });
  }

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
      // HERE: you always want to prevent default, so do this first
      e.preventDefault()
        if (!isFormValid()) {
           //message of error in the screen, maybe sweet alerts
           console.log('falta algo')
        } else{ 
          sendEmail(e)
        }
    };



  return (
    <div className={classes.section}>
      <div className={classes.container}>
        <GridContainer justify="center">
          <GridItem xs={12} sm={12} md={4}>
            <Card>
              <!-- HERE: use the FORM submit function and make sure to pass the event down to handleSubmit(e)@ -->
              <form className={classes.form} onSubmit={(e) => handleSubmit(e)}>
                <CardHeader style={{ fontWeight: "fontWeightBold" }} color='primary' className={classes.cardHeader}>
                  <h4>Let's create something together </h4>

                </CardHeader>
                <CardBody>
                  <CustomInput
                    labelText="Name..."
                    id="name"
                    required={true}
                    formControlProps={{
                      required: true,
                      fullWidth: true
                    }}
                    inputProps={{ 
                      required: true,
                      onChange: handleChange(),
                      id:'name',
                      value: values.name,
                      type: "text",
                      endAdornment: (
                        <InputAdornment position="end">
                          <People className={classes.inputIconsColor} />
                        </InputAdornment>
                      )
                    }}
                  />
                  <CustomInput
                    labelText="Email..."
                    id="email"
                    type='email'
                    required={true}
                    onChange={handleChange()}
                    formControlProps={{
                      required: true,
                      fullWidth: true
                    }}
                    inputProps={{
                      required: true,
                      onChange: handleChange(),
                      id:'email',
                      value: values.email,
                      type: "email",
                      endAdornment: (
                        <InputAdornment position="end">
                          <Email className={classes.inputIconsColor} />
                        </InputAdornment>
                      )
                    }}
                  />
                  <CustomInput
                    labelText="Be free..."
                    id="message"
                    required={true}
                    formControlProps={{
                      size: 'large', 
                      rows: '4',
                      required: true,
                      fullWidth: true
                    }}
                    inputProps={{
                      multiline: true,
                      required: true,
                      onChange: handleChange(),
                      id:'message',
                      value: values.message,
                      multiline: true,
                      type: "text",
                      endAdornment: (
                        <InputAdornment position="end">
                          <Icon className={classes.inputIconsColor}>
                            <SendIcon  className={classes.inputIconsColor}/>
                          </Icon> 
                        </InputAdornment>
                      ),
                      autoComplete: "off"
                    }}
                  />
                </CardBody>
                <CardFooter className={classes.cardFooter}>
                  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
                </CardFooter>
              </form>
            </Card>
          </GridItem>
        </GridContainer>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Biggest take away so far, you are confusing the form logic a bit. A form relies on a submit button which is of type input. Also, make use of the onSubmit function together with the submit input element.

If you want to work with a form and prevent the default event on submit, you have to use an input type submit button and the `onSubmit` function of the form. Since this is a react app and you are not relying on form events at all, you could also do it differently (and keep your styled button). See [this guide](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_form_submit.asp) on how to submit your form with a custom button.

Comment: sorry, I already edited the first comment. My problem o  the beginning was the “preventDefault” of undefined and now this error “index.js:106 uncaught expected the html form element or the style selector of form”

Answer (score 0):

Had same issue, solved it by adding id to the form and passing it to the emailJS method.

Add form-id to emailjs method:

```
emailjs
  .sendForm(
    "service_<id>",
    "template_<id>",
    "#contact-form",
    "user_<id>"
  )
```

Then to the form tag:

```
id="contact-form"
```